# php grep exec or system regex

Tags: php, grep, system

How can I grep a pattern that can include spaces, commas etc using `exec` or `system` in PHP, and return one string separated by a comma each result. If needed, I can make use of awk or sed to separated by comma.

So for instance, if the pattern to search is: `hello worl`
then return:

```
$result = 'hello world, hello worlds, hello worldy';
```

Any ideas will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Why do you need to `grep` using `exec`/`system`? What's wrong with `preg_match`?

Comment: 4 huge files, I assume it might be faster!

Answer (score 0):

Check out [`escapeshellarg()`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php) and [`escapeshellcmd()`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellcmd.php).

### Edit:

Is this in just one file?  If you're not searching across the system then just use the built-in functions, they'll be plenty fast.

Comment: sorry forgot to mention, actually there are 4 files.

Comment: then you might do better with a recursive grep if you feel like parsing the output.  It's really up to you, just use `escapeshellarg()` to safely escape whatever you're using into a single argument.